# Dice throwing simulator

Tags: python

I am making a dice throwing simulator that generates N rolls for me, but assigns a name to each roll, for example:

```
[5,7,8]
```

then print

```
Player 1: 5
Player 2: 7
Player 3: 8
```

this is my code:

```
import random

players = int(input("Number of players:"))
throw_i = [random.randint(1, (30 * 1)) for _ in range(players)]
print(throw_i)

#Print results
for i in range (1, players+1):
     print('Player', i,':', throw_i[0]+1)
```

An example output of my code is:

```
[22, 13, 18, 13]
Player 1 : 23
Player 2: 23
Player 3 : 23
Player 4 : 23
```

It does not work!

Comment: It would improve this question if you could explain what output you expect as comparison to your example output, to show why "It does not work!" is true. See [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for comment! I'm not the best at writing in English, I'll improve it!, but at the beginning of my question I put an example of how I want my output to be, next time I'll try to be clearer. @AdamSmith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
print('Player', i,':', throw_i[0]+1)
```

with

```
print('Player', i,':', throw_i[i-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The last two lines are the problem.

```py
for i in range (1, players+1):
     print('Player', i,':', throw_i[0]+1)
```

This reads:

> For every number between 1 and (players+1), print out some text followed by the *first* throw, plus one

That `throw_i[0]` always refers to the very first number generated. Maybe you mean to do `throw_i[i]`, which will be off-by-one since lists start with zero and you're starting with 1, so `throw_i[i-1]`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using 30 as max range of randint but a dice has 6.

```
import random

players = int(input("Number of players:"))
throw_i = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(players)] # As far as i know a dice has numbers from 1 to 6. 
print(throw_i)

#Print results
for i in range (0, players):
     print('Player', i+1,':', throw_i[i])
```

Input: `Number of players:4`

Output:

```
[4, 5, 6, 4]

Player 1 : 4
Player 2 : 5
Player 3 : 6
Player 4 : 4
```

EDIT: As pointed out by @Adam that die can be of other sides as well. Then you should just change:

```
for i in range (0, players):
         print('Player', i+1,':', throw_i[i])
```

Comment: You've changed their code in a non-obvious way to fix the problem, but then call out something irrelevant (dice do not always have 6 sides -- and while a 30-sided die is weird, d20, d12, d10, d8, d6, and d4 are all very common configurations)

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks for the comment i have added that as well!